# How to measure field-of-view of a camera with fisheye Lens?

Tags: optics, field-of-view, distortion, fisheye

For a camera with a rectilinear lens a simple measurement would
consist of taking images from known distance of an object of known size.
For example using a sheet of paper as an object set on a wall perpendicular 
to optical axis of the camera and taking images from several distances to have 
an average value (or do linear fit). 
Then say horizontal fov can be calculated from images as

hfov = 2 * arctan(Img_w/(2*d))

where

- Img_w = Img_wp * (Obj_w/Obj_wp)
- Img_w - image width       [mm]
- Img_wp    - Image width in pixels
- Obj_w - object width      [mm]
- Obj_wp    - object width in pixels
- d - distance to object    [mm]

As I understand, for rectilinear lenses and fixed distance to the object the ratio Obj_w/Obj_wp would not change 
regardless of where the object is located in the image.
But for lenses with distortion like fisheye, this ratio would depend on the object location on the image and 
the method would not work.

Is there a simple similar method to measure fov for fisheye lenses ?

What method is used in the industry to measure fov of camera systems ?

Since I have a camera a with small S-Mount lenses and working distances are about ~1 meter, one possible way could be  to have a ruler or tape measure set on a wall spanning the whole image horizontally. Then calculating the fov from the distance d and scene width seen on the tape measure in the image. But I'm not sure if that would work.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would just put the camera on a tripod in an open space. Have a friend stand in the scene. Have them walk as far to the right as they can while still remaining in frame. Mark that point. Do the same on the left. Now draw a straight line (or stretch a piece of string) from the point on the floor that is below center of the tripod to each mark (again on the floor). Use a protractor to measure the angle formed at the tripod.